# What's the best distributed file system for Apache Mesos beside HDFS?

Tags: filesystems, distributed-computing, mesos, mesosphere

I found lot of documentation for using HDFS on MESOS, but I'm looking for a non JVM file system. My goal is to decrease resources consumption.

Comment: What I found as solutions: 1) Ceph (ceph.com), good choice and have a mesos framework, 2) GluterFS (gluster.org) looks easy to deploy, 3) Quobyte, have a mesos framework. But I didn't found a binary to test it (not OpenSource).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at https://github.com/vivint-smarthome/ceph-on-mesos; This framework targets Mesos directly and can be used with or without DCOS.

Answer (score 1):

You could give [Quobyte](https://github.com/quobyte/mesos-framework) a try; it's written in C++ and soon also [available](https://docs.mesosphere.com/reference/servicestatus/) via the DCOS.

As a general intro I suggest to check out the MesosCon Europe 2015 presentation [Apache Mesos Storage Now and Future](http://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/Mesoscon%202015%20-%20Mesos%20Filesystems.pdf).

Comment: Thank you Michael, looks a really good solution for my case. Excellent news.

Comment: Couldn't test it, there is no binary to download and it's not OpenSource.

Comment: Ping me at michael.hausenblas AT mesosphere.io and I can arrange it @ChristianKakesa …